# I get req.params.id = 'favicon.ico' when I send GET /whatever to custom route 'GET /:id'

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

(Sails.js)

How to ignore the favicon browser request and get the id that I want?

router.js

```
  'GET /:id': 'UrlController.findOne'
```

UrlController.js

```
  /**
   * `UrlController.findOne()`
   */
  findOne: function (req, res) {
    var id = req.param('id');

    console.log(id);

    Url.findOne({where: {id: id}}).exec(function(err, url) {
      return res.redirect(url.target);
    })
  },
```

Any way to simply prioritize static files before routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a more elegant solution:

Change:

router.js

```
  'GET /:id': 'UrlController.findOne'
```

To:

```
  'GET /:id': {
    controller: "UrlController",
    action: "findOne",
    skipAssets: true
  },
```

Also thanks to all for guiding me towards the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create an extra route for `/favicon.ico` before that route that just returns 404 (or maybe a fancy icon).

Alternatively your library of choice probably supports regex filters for route arguments and you could set up one that only matches valid IDs based on length, characters etc, assuming your IDs have some sort of format.

You might also be able to suppress the request by putting `<meta>` elements in your page to tell the browser to look for an icon elsewhere if you have one.

Comment: The tag @matti mentioned would be `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/favicon.png">`  See [here](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon)

Comment: Plus about fifteen other tags if you want to support less capable mobile devices such as iOS properly, so I didn't list them all here. Also `image/png` with `.ico` is a bit bizarre...

Comment: Sorry for the *typo*

Comment: Any way to simply prioritize static files before routes?

Answer (score 0):

Using serve-favicon will create a route and thus prevent 404.

```
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
```